# selectbox inserting values multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require '../common/connect-db.php';
require_once 'admin-template.php';
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<?php
 // add button
if(isset($_POST['add_dayoff'])) {
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO dayoff (fname,lname,datef)
VALUES ('$_POST[select1]')";
mysqli_query($db,$AddQuery);
};
?>
<?php
$query="SELECT DISTINCT fname, lname FROM employees";
$result = $db->query($query);
?>
<table><caption>Dayoff Table</caption>
     <tr>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Employee Dayoff</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
<td><select name="select1" id="select1" >
<?php
echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['fname'] . $row['lname'] . "'>" . $row['fname'] ." ". $row['lname'] . "</option>";
}
?>

<td><input type="date"  name="date" required /></td>
</select></td>
<td><input type="submit"  name="add_dayoff" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

the primary key is `email` in e`mployees` table, i know it's not a secure way to do it, and i should use prepare statements, but it's just a small project. 'dayoff' has an auto incremented int 'id' as primary key.

So what happens is that all records are inserted more than once. And some records `fname` and `lname` are concatenated and stored in `fname` in `dayoff` table

Comment: it will not work: $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO dayoff (fname,lname,datef)
VALUES ('$_POST[select1]')"; , it is wrong syntax query.

Comment: what $_POST[select1] contain?

Comment: @VigneswaranS it contains fname, lname and date, and it works, just insert them many times though

Comment: @GoudaElalfy actually it works, read my previous comment, just inserts them many times

Comment: i dont think it will work. as  Gouda Elalfy says it is a syntax error

Comment: @VigneswaranS assuming it wont work, what's your alternavive solution? doing two select boxes for fname and lname? tried that, same issue. is there something im not seeing here

Comment: i think it has to do with the loop, it loads select with everything it has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error

```
INSERT INTO dayoff (fname,lname,datef) VALUES ($_POST[select1]).$_POST[select1] will contains fnamelname.
```

Moreover you didn't get `date` value `ie:$_post['date'].` Try this and let me know the result

```
  <?php
    require_once 'admin-template.php';
    ?>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
    <?php
    // add button
    if(isset($_POST['add_dayoff'])) {
    $fname=$_POST['select1'];// get the value which stores firstname-lastname
    $n=explode('-',$fname);//explode the value with -
    $datef=$_POST['date'];
    $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO dayoff (fname,lname,datef) VALUES ('$n[0]','$n[1]',$datef)";// query should be like this 
    mysqli_query($db,$AddQuery);
    };
    ?>
    <?php
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT fname, lname FROM employees";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    ?>
    <table><caption>Dayoff Table</caption>
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Employee Dayoff</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="select1" id="select1" >
    <?php
    echo '<option value="">Please select...</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='". $row['fname']."-".$row['lname'] . "'>" . $row['fname'] ." ". $row['lname'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    <td><input type="date"  name="date" required /></td>
    </select></td>
   <td><input type="submit"  name="add_dayoff" /></td>
   </tr>
    </table>
```